# Sum a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, math, sum, sequence, series

Given: Two positive integers a and b (a

Return: The sum of all odd integers from a through b, inclusively.

```
    #My code: 
    a = 100
    b = 200
    for i in range(a,b):
        if i%2 == 1:
            print i
```

At the moment it's just showing a drop down list of all the odd integers. I do not know how to affix a "range" to this properly, if need be. How can I add on to my code above to get the sum of all the odd integers?

Thanks

Comment: Summation works with `+`. You sum up values by adding them to a variable, maybe `sum`. You set this variable to 0 at the beginning and add your `i` values to that during the iteration.

Comment: BTW, why do you see a drop down list here? I don't see where it would be generated.

Comment: Note that `range` goes only from `a` to `b-1`, so you should use `range(a, b+1)`.

Comment: Sorry about the "drop down" list definition. It's rather misleading. I was in a rush. Can anybody suggest a better title perhaps???

Comment: Actually this is just a math problem, similar to the one [attributed to Gauss](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57919.html). Try something like `sumrange = lambda high, low, step = (high - low) * (high + low) // (2 * step)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rather quick way to do it would be:

```
result = 0
for i in range(a,b+1):
  if i%2 == 1:
    result += i
print result
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name.

Comment: Also: what is the reasoning as to why result=0?

Comment: @Cloud to define a variable to hold the sum?

Comment: a faster way might be to check if a is odd and if not, `a += 1` and then `for i in range(a, b+1, 2):`  and then don't check for odd numbers anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Sum all the numbers between `a` and `b` if odd.

```
sum(i for i in xrange(a, b) if i%2)
```

Comment: Nope. Unable to get the sum. Still getting this initial result:101
103
105
107
109
111
113
115....

Comment: Double checked and it's still occurring. Any other ways or suggestions?

Comment: do you need a set of [] or ()?

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. If you think about the math, though, it's a lot like [Gauss's old problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20171225182632/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57919.html). Gauss was asked to add the numbers between 1 and 100, and he realized that each pair of high and low values summed to 101 (100 + 1, 99 + 2, 98 + 3…)

```
high = b
low = a
```

So we have to multiply some number of `b + a` values. How many are there? For *all* the integers, that's just

```
num_pairs = (high-low) // 2
```

Then we multiply that number by `high + low` to get the answer:

```
result = (high + low) * num_pairs
```

But you only want every other ones, so we divide by two again:

```
result //= 2
```

Totally:

```
def sumrange(low, high, step):
     num_pairs = (high - low) // 2
     result = (high + low) * num_pairs
     return result // step
```

or `sumrange = lambda low, high, step: (high - low) * (high + low) // (2 * step)`

Now this still isn't *quite* an answer to your question, because it needs to be offset depending on whether your low value is odd, and whether your high value is included or excluded. But I will leave that as an exercise.

Making this a CW answer so someone can edit if my math is messy.

Answer (score 0):

Some mathematical tricks can solve your problem much efficiently.

For example, sum of first n odd numbers = n*n  `square(n)`

So you can use for

> Sum of odd numbers [m,n] = n*n - (m-2)*(m-2) `where m!=1` and `m and n are odds`

One more useful analysis is, AP (arithmetic progression)

> Formula : (n/2)*(a+l) `where n= no. of elements, a = first term, l= last term`

Here,

a = m [if m is odd]

a = m+1 [if m is even]

l = n [if n is odd]

l = n-1 [if n is even]

n = ( ( l - a ) / 2 ) + 1

By applying in code, you can easily get the answer...

Answer (score 0):

And the numpy version of the solution:

```
import numpy as np
a = 100
b = 200
r = np.linspace(a,b-1,b-a)
r = np.sum(np.mod(r,2)*r)
print(r)
```

Comment: yay for numpy! this solution runs pretty quickly